# My MacBook Pro only boots up with Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, mac, multi-boot, macbook-pro, boot-camp

I've installed Windows 7 on my Mac with Boot Camp and I had Dual Boot on my screen when I want to select to chose Operating Systems. Yesterday, when I turned on My MacBook Pro (MD 322) it boots up with Windows 7 automatically. I think my OS X installation is damaged and I can't check the OS X partition in Windows.

What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the control panel and in the search box in the upper right, type `boot camp`.  You should see the Boot Camp disk drive icon below.  Open it and it let you change your boot partition.

Comment: I could not find something similar in my control panel.

Comment: @MohammadHasanEsfahanian - This means you didn't install Windows through boot camp.  Which means your OS X installation is gone.  Which means you will have to install it again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

1. Turn off your Mac
2. Turn it back on and soon as you strike the power button, hold the <kbd>Option</kbd> button until you see the screen giving the choice of booting with your OS X or Windows

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Restart the Mac, when it boot press the "ALT" key
The computer will start and give you the option to choose wich OS to boot into.